# R svytable "inf" results; does not match Stata "svy" code

Tags: r, statistics

New to R and have encountered two issues in coding using the "survey" package:

(1) Code from svytable using "survey" package does not correspond to Stata estimates from svy: tab. I call

```
svyd.nation <- svydesign(ids = ~1, probs = ~wt_national, strata = ~stratum, data=nats.sub)
svytable(formula = ~wpev, design = svyd.nation, Ntotal = 100)
```

where the equivalent Stata would be:

```
svyset [pw=wt_national], strata(stratum)
svy: tab wpev
```

These give different %s for the tabulations. Any ideas as to what I've done incorrectly in R?

(2) Alternative weights --- which I've verified in R have the same distribution as in Stata --- don't appear to work in R for some unknown reason.

```
svyd.st <- svydesign(ids = ~1, probs = ~wt_state, strata = ~stratum, data=nats.sub)
svytable(~wpev, design = svyd.st, Ntotal=100)
```

which produces:

```
wpev
0 1
```

and 
    svytable(~wpev,  svyd.st)

which produces

```
wpev
0   1 
Inf Inf
```

Why are these alternative weights -- which work in Stata when resetting svyset -- not working in R? Any insights would be appreciated!!

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like in one instance you are working with "weights" that are inverse-weightings and perhaps in the other case with one where "weights" are case-weightings?

Comment: Both wt_national and wt_state are the inverse probability of sample selection (though, respectively, for the nation and for  states). It's just unclear to me why wt_national does not compute the same--though the code appears similar to that listed in the documentation--I know that Stata code is correct because it corroborates published results from a federal agency.